# Create a diamond in the picture

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing

I'm going to write a program that does a diamond within a specific image
i wrote this code

```
Img=zeros(256,256);
for x=1:256
    for y=1:256
     if(y-x==128)||(y-x==-128)||(y+x==128)
           Img(x,y)=1;
     end

    end
end
imshow(Img);
```

[image]

I could draw three sides diamond.
How do I draw a fourth side؟

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luis Mendo nailed the last condition in the `if` statement of your loop to draw the last line.  His solution is what you are looking for should you want a `for` loop solution.

However, if you want something more vectorized, a more efficient way to do this would be to define a grid of co-ordinates using [`meshgrid`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/meshgrid.html) then simply apply a chain of `logical` operations to get your diamond.  In other words:

```
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:256, 1:256);
Img = abs(x-y) == 128 | x+y == 384 | x+y == 128;
imshow(Img);
```

We thus get:

[image]

---

In general, for a given size image that is square, you can adapt this to any size image by:

```
N = 256; %// Change here - width/height of your image
[x,y] = meshgrid(1:N, 1:N);
Img = abs(x-y) == floor(N/2) | x+y == floor(3*N/2) | x+y == floor(N/2);
imshow(Img);
```

I've placed a `floor` operation in case you want to specify an image size that is not evenly divisible by 2.  However, the symmetry of the diamond may not look correct, but the code will work regardless.

Answer (score 3):

The condition you are missing is `y+x==384`. So, replace the `if` line by

```
if (y-x==128)||(y-x==-128)||(y+x==128)||(y+x==384)
```

The condition would look more symmetric if your coordinates were centered around `0`, say `-128:128`:

```
Img=zeros(257,257);
for x=-128:128
    for y=-128:128
        if(y-x==128)||(y-x==-128)||(y+x==128)||(y+x==-128)
           Img(129+x,129+y)=1;
        end
    end
end
imshow(Img);
```

As noted by @kkuilla, this can be easily vectorized. See [@rayryeng's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27426255/2586922).

Comment: I'm waiting for the vectorised solution...:-)

Comment: @kkuilla Hahaha. Hadn't thought of that, but yes, it can be done easily

Comment: I'm removing the vectorized part because it already appears in [@rayryeng's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27426255/2586922)

Comment: @kkuilla .i want use this code for compression image via furie series.ok?

Comment: @LuisMendo - I hope you didn't mind me taking your last `if` statement and making it vectorized :) I didn't want to pull the rug under you as you did figure out what was wrong with the code first.  BTW, thanks for linking to my answer :)

Comment: @rayryeng No problem! I really hadn't thought about vectorizing until kkuilla mentioned it :-)

Comment: @LuisMendo - I was actually about to finish writing something vectorized when kkuilla mentioned it to you :). I just wanted to make sure there wasn't a misunderstanding though.

Comment: @rayryeng Of course there's no misunderstanding! Thanks for being so careful about that :-)